# How to optimize this recursion function?

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming

This is really similar to Fibonacci Sequence problem. I understand the DP optimization with Fibonacci function using the for loop, but I'm having hard time to connect to this problem.

The recursion function I want to optimize is:

def cal(n):
if n <= 0:
return 1
else:
return cal(n-25)+cal(n-26)

Comment: `from itertools import lru_cache` then add `@lru_cache` decorator before your function. all done ✅

Comment: Can you please write the code out?

Comment: line 1) `from itertools...` line 2) `@lru_cache`, line 3) `def cal(n): ...`, line 4) `print(cal(some_number))`

Comment: @underflow - can you show us a few expected outputs?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may help:

(It's inspired by previous post)

```py
from functools import cache

@cache
def cal(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return cal(n-25) + cal(n-26)



print(cal(100))
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a "for loop optimization" is that we calculate cal(0), cal(1), cal(2), ... consecutively. And when we want cal(n), we already have cal(n-25) and cal(n-26) stored in an array.

So, the following solution has linear complexity for non-negative n:

```
def cal(n):
    mem = [1]  # cal(0) is 1
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        num = 1 if i - 25 < 0 else mem[i - 25]
        num += 1 if i - 26 < 0 else mem[i - 26]
        mem.append (num)
    return mem[-1]
```

One can further optimize to make all the values cal(1), cal(2), ..., cal(n) globally available after calculating the last of them.

Comment: Try it with cal(100)  or cal(10) both got this - ```IndexError: list index out of range```?

Comment: It's well explained and working perfectly.